# how to compare values of a datatable from two datatable and subtract them

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datatable

I am coding in c# and I want to compare the "quantity" in "sell" datatable with "buy" datatable and if "quantity" in "buy" table is greater then I need to subtract "buy" table from "sell" and "quantity" or else just continue. Please tell how to take the value for comparision. I have made the coding as below but its showing error.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            var sql = @"select scriptname,accnum,Quantity,price from transac where transactio = 'Sell' and scriptname = '" + TextBox2.Text + "' and accnum ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
            var sqll = @"select scriptname,accnum,Quantity,price from transac where transactio = 'Buy' and scriptname ='" + TextBox2.Text + "' and accnum ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqll, conn);
            var dataTablebuy = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dataTablebuy);
            var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            var dataTablesell = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTablesell);
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTablesell.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataRow rw in dataTablebuy.Rows)
                {
                    if (rw["Quantity"] > row["Quantity"])
                    {
                        rw["Quantity"] = rw["Quantity"] - row["Quantity"];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            Response.Write("error" + sqlEx.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("error" + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: you probably need to cast..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if (double.Parse(rw["Quantity"].ToString()) > double.Parse(row["Quantity"].ToString()))
 {
     rw["Quantity"] = double.Parse(rw["Quantity"].ToString()) - double.Parse(row["Quantity"].ToString())
 }
```

Comment: how do you guarantee the quantity is not null? ie.. i would update the select statement as well.. ie ISNULL(Quantity,0)

Comment: Check it for null like if (rw["Quantity"] == null) { }

Comment: it's missing from your code.. anyway there's room for sql injection attack from his code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to provide more feasible option in case you need any alternative.

I just covered your scenario in query itself. I joined tables and got data as per your need

You just get data using this query.

Please frame query for c# code

select T1.scriptname,T1.accnum,(case when (T2.Quantity>T1.Quantity) then  (T2.Quantity-T1.Quantity) else T1.Quantity end) as Quantity,T1.price 
from transac T1,transac T2 
where 
T1.transactio = 'Sell' 
and 
T2.transactio = 'Buy'
and 
T1.scriptname = ' TextBox2.Text ' 
and 
T1.accnum =' TextBox1.Text '
and 
T2.scriptname ='TextBox2.Text' 
and 
T2.accnum ='TextBox1.Text' 
and 
T1.scriptname = T2.scriptname 
and 
T2.accnum = T2.accnum